# match two data sets and produce a result from a third cell in excel 2013

Tags: excel-2013

I have the following data set  (data set 1)

```
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Home Team   |  Away Team  |  Result  |
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Team 1      |    Team 2   |    4     |
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Team 3      |    Team 4   |    5     | <-- this one
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Team 5      |    Team 6   |    0     |
+---------------+-------------+----------+
```

In another data set (data set 2) I have the following

```
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Home Team   |  Away Team  |  Result  |
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Team 7      |    Team 2   |          |
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Team 3      |    Team 4   |          | <-- this one
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Team 9      |    Team 5   |          |
+---------------+-------------+----------+
```

I would like to go through data set 1 and if both the away Home team and the away team match, i.e the fixture, then to put the result from data set one into the corresponding column in data set 2.

How would I do this?

Notes

I want to try to avoid VBA, I prefer functions. But if there is no other way, I don't mind VBA

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this sort of thing without VBA is to create a new column to the left of data set 1 (which can be made hidden if you want) to serve as keys for a `VLOOKUP` which is used to populate the final column of data set 2. The result looks something like this:

[image]

A2 contains the formula

```
=CONCATENATE(TRIM(B2),":",TRIM(C2))
```

And D5 contains the formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(TRIM(B7),":",TRIM(C7)),$A$1:$D$4,4,FALSE),"")
```

(each formula copied down the relevant range of cells).